# Setting type to objects/arrays created "on the fly" with Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

Is there a way to define that an array
`['left', 'center', 'right']` is not a `string[]` but `Position[]` in this code example without storing it in a variable:

```
type Position = 'left' | 'center' | 'right';

const sidePositions: Position[] = ['left', 'center', 'right'].filter(p => p !== 'center');
```

Example is a very simplified version of what we are actually doing in our project, we cannot use just `['left', 'right']` array instead. The following workaround works but we won't get a TS error if we mistype some words and that can cause some human errors:

`const sidePositions: Position[] = (['foo', 'bar', 'right'] as Position[]).filter(p => p !== 'center');`

Of course it is possible to store the array in a typed variable first, but in our case it is less convenient. Here's a link to [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwJbCXAdlAvFA5AGwgDNhcoAfPAYwnWAgCczLcGkBzAC1IG4AoPlQwJgUZABMI8ZKmEAuWIhRp0AbQC62KKoLFSAGmq16TQ6w7dc6gHREk+EwAow2AHxQXAQiw5cNOoy4AJQ8QA)

Comment: `([...] as const).filter(...)`? https://tsplay.dev/wep5EW

Comment: it is better than ```as Position[]``` because we get an error, but we still get an error not in the right place

Comment: What do you mean "an error not in the right place"? Fundamentally it's all just working around the correct solution: assign the array to a typed variable first.

Comment: Array ```['foo', 'bar', 'right']``` should be marked as invalid because it should be of type ```Position[]``` and it is clearly not. Now we see that ```sidePositions``` variable is invalid which is correct, but it is a result of other array being invalid

Comment: It suggests how to write a type but how should we specify that the created on the fly array is of a specific type?

Comment: @johnsharpe's suggestion is a good one.  The whole line is in error; it's a bit strange to insist that one particular part of it is the "right" place for the error.  It's like saying that in `1 + 2 = 4` the error is specifically the `2` ("it should be `3`").  I mean, I guess you can think that, but someone else looking at it might reasonably say that it's the `4` ("it should be `5`") or `=` ("it should be `<`") etc etc.  The compiler isn't human; it has to use heuristics for issuing errors, and the error here seems quite reasonable to me.

Comment: It looks like you want the so-called `satisfies` operator as discussed in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920.  If it existed, you could write `(['foo', 'bar', 'right'] satisfies Position[])` and it would check without asserting or widening.  It doesn't currently exist in TS.  See the answer to the linked question for more information and the current workarounds.

Comment: That ```satisfies Position[]``` would be a perfect solution in this case, I would actually accept that as an answer to my question if I could